# how to use $subtract with $inc of document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can anyone shed light on what this refers to?

```
db.getCollection("test_index").update({ "_id" : ObjectId("5c494913d5cddcf38e8b45dd")},
{
    $inc : {'user.$.quantity_export' : {'$subtract' : ['$user.quantity_export','$user.quantity_remain']}},
    $set : {'user.$.quantity_remain' : 5}
}

)
```

> "writeError" : {      "code" : 14,        "errmsg" : "Cannot increment with
>   non-numeric argument: {user.$.quantity_export: { $subtract: [
>   \"$user.quantity_export\", \"$user.quantity_remain\" ] }}"    }

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you can not use `$subtract` in `update` or `find` method of mongo, it should be only used in `Aggregation`, so have a look into below query using `subtract`

```
db.test_index.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5c6017b31765cd7b27eb473a")}, {"abc" : {$subtract : ["$user.quantity_export","$user.quantity_remain"]} } )
```

It will produce an error of below type:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unsupported projection option: abc: { $subtract: [ \"$user.quantity_export\", \"$user.quantity_remain\" ] }",
    "code" : 2,
    "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

And this value will be placed in your `$inc` for the field `'user.$.quantity_export'` i.e `$inc : {'user.$.quantity_export' : {'$subtract' : ['$user.quantity_export','$user.quantity_remain']}}` this is causing the error. You can simply verify by below query with error you are getting:

```
> db.test_index.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5c6017b31765cd7b27eb473a")}, {$inc : {"user.quantity_export" : {"Bad values" : "abc"} }} )
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 14,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {user.quantity_export: { Bad values: \"abc\" }}"
    }
})
>
```

> Now the solution to your problem is:

Since the `$subtract` are used in the `Aggregation` so you have to use the aggregation and update the fields using `$out` operator at the last stage of aggregation, for more details you can have a look at the official documentation of [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

For your information, the first query in this ans produce an error with `$subtract` but **will work with aggregation as**:

```
> db.test_index.aggregate([ {$match: {"_id" : ObjectId("5c6017b31765cd7b27eb473a")}}, {$project: {"abc" : {$subtract : ["$user.quantity_export","$user.quantity_remain"]} } } ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c6017b31765cd7b27eb473a"), "abc" : -10000 }
```